# compare and add the list of elements into another list

Tags: java

I am trying to compare and add the list of objects inside another list using java8 stream API.
Below are the sample json.

**studentList:**

```
 [{
  sid:1,
  id:10,
  sname :"xyz"
  sPassOut : "2019"
}, {
  sid:2,
  id:20,
  sname :"abc"
  sPassOut : "2020"
},{
   sid:3,
   id:30,
  sname :"ppp"
  sPassOut : "2021"
},
{
   sid:1,
   id:10,
  sname :"ppp"
  sPassOut : "2021"
},
{
   sid:2,
  id:20,
  sname :"ppp"
  sPassOut : "2021"
}]
```

**myList:**

```
  [{
    id:10,
    status:"active",
    studentList:[]
   },{id:20, 
      status:"active",
       studentList:[]
   },{id:30, 
      status:"active",
       studentList:[]
   },{id:40, 
      status:"active",
       studentList:[]
   }]
```

I want to add the studentList elements in the myList for each matching **id** value.

tried the below code, but it is not giving the expected result.

```
studentList.forEach(studList -> {
    studList.setStudentList(myList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(MyList:: getId)));
});
```

Expected JSON:

```
[
    {
    id: 10,
    status: "active",
    studentList: [
            {
  sid: 1,
  id: 10,
  sname : "xyz"
  sPassOut : "2019"
            },
            {
   sid: 4,
   id: 10,
  sname : "ppp"
  sPassOut : "2021"
            }
        ]
    },
    {id: 20, 
      status: "active",
       studentList: [
            {
  sid: 2,
  id: 20,
  sname : "abc"
  sPassOut : "2020"
            },
            {
   sid: 5,
  id: 20,
  sname : "ppp"
  sPassOut : "2021"
            }
        ]
    },
    {id: 30, 
      status: "active",
       studentList: [
            {
   sid: 3,
   id: 30,
  sname : "ppp"
  sPassOut : "2021"
            }
        ]
    },
    {id: 40, 
      status: "active",
       studentList: []
    }
]
```

I wan to add the elements from studentList grouped together with matching id value in the myList as shown in the sample json above.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the required student list using the stream api, you need to filter the students to get only students with a certain id and then collect them into a list. An example of this is shown below:

```
studentList.stream().filter(student -> student.id == ID_TO_MATCH).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

In the code above, `ID_TO_MATCH` represents the the student id to find for each section of `myList`. See the following example of getting `ID_TO_MATCH`:

```
myList.forEach(section -> {
    int ID_TO_MATCH = section.id;
};
```

These code snippets can be combined to produce the solution:

```
myList.forEach(section -> {
    int id = section.id;
    List<Student> studentsFound = studentList.stream().filter(student -> student.id == id).collect(Collectors.toList())
    section.setStudentList(studentsFound);
};
```